# Http Client GetAsync await taking too long/not returning when called from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller, async-await

I am trying to call the Googles Distance Matrix API. I am experiencing long delay with no response being returned when I make a call from the controller. However, when I call it straight from my test it works fine.

Controller > Repository > Client > Googles API -- **Long Delay/no response**

Test > Repository> Client > Googles API -- **works fine.**

Have I missed anything in my controller? Do i have to put await/async on my controller? If yes, why does it work without it from test class?

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DistanceMatrixRequest request)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var response = _repository.GetDistance(request);

        //do something
    }

    return View();
}
```

### Repository

```
public DistanceMatrixResponse GetDistance(DistanceMatrixRequest request)
{
    var response = _client.GetDistance(request);

    var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DistanceMatrixResponse>(json);

    return model;
}
```

### Client

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetDistance(DistanceMatrixRequest request)
{
    var uri = BuildUri(request);
    return GetDistanceAsync(uri).Result;
}

private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDistanceAsync(string uri)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    return response;
}
```

### Test Class - works fine when i call from my test

```
[TestMethod]
public void GivenRequestIsValid_APIReturnsResponseMessage()
{
    //Arrange
    var model = new DistanceMatrixRequest()
    {
        Origin = "Manchester",
        Destination = "London"
    };

    // Act
    var response = _repository.GetDistance(model);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(response);
}
```

Comment: That is because of the mixing of async/await and blocking calls like `.Result` which can lead to deadlocks. Go async all the way or sync all the way but try not to mix them.

Comment: Stephen Cleary has a good article about it https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: There are better duplicates, but I couldn't find them now if someone have better link handy - ping me to add another dup.